# How to package by stage/region using the Serverless Framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I would like to know how to create a separate package per stage/region, because I want to have the package step create a separate bundle for each variation of stage/region I'm deploying to.

[The docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/package/) indicate I can call the package command, however when running I get:

> Command "package" not found, Run "serverless help" for
>        a list of all available commands.

These are the commands I've tried running but with the error mentioned

```
serverless package -s dev -r us-east-1 -p .serverless/us-east-1 -v

serverless deploy -s dev -l -r us-east-1 -v -p .serverless/us-east-1
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is a published documentation for the `package` command, it is not available yet in version **1.11**. It [is planned to ship](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3467) only in the next version, **1.12**.

In v **1.11**, the [`deploy`](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/deploy/) command always executes the `package` command under the the hood, but you don't have control about this packaging process. You could use the `--noDeploy` option to create local files with the selected stage/region, but running `deploy` again will override the package, ignoring what was previously set. It will deploy to the stage/region of the options parameters (if provided) or look into the serverless.yml file.

Another problem is that v **1.11** does not support the `--path` option, so you would not be able to select where to save the package nor to select where to find the package to deploy. Again, you need to wait for the next version to use those features.

Comment: Thanks @Zanon. I'll wait for the 1.12 release. Appreciate the insight.

Comment: @Cojmcc [v1.12](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-v1.12.0/) was released yesterday. This feature should be working now.